# Back up camera power and ground

Tags: electrical

Ok I'm hooking up a backup camera to my trucks aftermarket head unit. The backup camera has the standard power and ground then rca jack that connects video to the Head unit. When I got everything hooked up it worked but it had horizontal line noise in the video. I thought it may be a bad ground so I was going to test a new ground location while my wife watched the video to see if it cleared up. Thing is when I removed the ground it cleared up. I tried 3 different ground points and they all made the video have noise. The only way I can get it to have clear video is too leave the ground undone. Will this hurt anything?

Comment: Where are you picking up the live feed for the camera? Reverse switch? A lot of cars output more than 14+ volts when no auxiliary components are running, it could be over voltage, the most logical method to me would to run the camera of a separate relay.

Comment: It's powered by the reverse light wire from the 7 way trailer plug harness.